# Display Toast message for user to key in all EditText if one or all is empty - Android

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, spinner, toast

I've an application where the user keys in his friend's information.My application have `Spinner`, 4 `EditText` and 3 `Buttons`(Save, Main Menu, View).

After the user click the Save button, if the user key in all required fields, it display Toast message "Your information is saved successfully! :D", and if the user did not key in one or all required fields it display Toast message "Please key in all the required fields. :o". 
I've tried coding using `if..else` statement refering to my SMS application -

```
String contact_fname = sendTo.getSelectedItem().toString();
//String contact_fname = textName.getText().toString();
String message = messageTxt.getText().toString();
if (contact_fname.length() > 0 && message.length() > 0)
    sendSMS(contact_fname, message);
else
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please choose a sender's name and enter your message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I replaced them with Spinner, and the 4 EditText. I tried refering to these codes(SMS app) above, but it failed =(

I just need to display the toast message (which I've mentioned) after user press save `Button`

Anyone knows how to do this? I appreciate any help provided =)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good thing is that you are using EditText. The reason it is good is that EditText comes with Form Validation. Not many use it though.

Example :

```
EditText firstName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.first_name);
if( firstName.getText().toString().length() == 0 )
    firstName.setError( "First name is required!" );
```

Hope this helps!